# Calculate $\int_\Gamma ze^{z}dz$ where $\Gamma$ is line from point $z_1=0$ to point $z_2=\frac{\pi i}{2}$

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-numbers

$$
\int_\Gamma ze^{z}dz\
$$
where $\Gamma$ is line from point $z_1=0$ to point $z_2=\frac{\pi i}{2}$

Hello, pls. how correctly calculate this example? I don't know what do with exponent..

Comment: You need to parametrize the curve $\Gamma$, e.g. let $z(t)=it$ where $t\in[0,\pi/2]$. Looks like integration by parts may be helpful too.

Comment: Yes, this know, but z(t)=t*e^(it), where t∈<0,π/2> ?

Comment: This integrand is analytic everywhere so for any domain $D$ containing $0$ and $\pi i /2$, $f$ has an antiderivative in $D$ and the contour integral only depends on the end points. So instead of parametrizing the curve, you could just find an antiderivative and evaluate at the end points.

Comment: @user227317 no, as I said use the substitution $z=it$. Also @ JessicaK's solution will also work. See also @ ChrisrianBlatter's answer.

Comment: $-\frac{\pi}{2}-i+1$ ??

Comment: @user227317 yes. See my answer for full details, but you got the answer! You can also use Blatter's approach too.

Answer (score 1):

A hint: The function
$$F(z):=(z-1)e^z$$
is a primitive of $$f(z):=ze^z\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Using parametrization:

$$\int_\Gamma ze^z dz.$$

You want to integrate along the line joining the complex points $0+i0$ to $0+i\pi/2$. We can parametrize this curve by setting $z=it$ with $t\in[0,\pi/2]$. Ok, so using the substitution $z=it$ we get $dz=idt$, so we have $$\int_0^{\pi/2} ite^{it}idt=-\int_0^{\pi/2}te^{it}dt=-\left[e^{i t} (1-i t)\right]_0^{\pi/2}=-(e^{i\pi/2}(1-i\pi/2)-1).$$ And this simplifies to $$-(i(1-i\pi/2)-1)=1-\pi/2-i.$$